# Who are these characters referenced in "Transformers: Age of Extinction"?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-age-of-extinction

Who are the

> "creators"

referenced in *Transformers: Age of Extinction*? Is there any such reference in the cartoon series, or comics?

Comment: @phantom42 - This is strictly in interest of the Fourth Transformer movie. No relevance to the question you mentioned. Does the question mention the movie anywhere?

Comment: @phantom42 - you could have mentioned this as an answer you know. There is no connection to the Creators mentioned in the movie TO the question you mentioned here. I would even have accepted that as an answer.

Comment: You asked if the "creators" are mentioned elsewhere in the cartoons or comics. The answers on the other questions explain who created the Transformers in the various incarnations. That's the same question to me. I understand the difference in opinion, but that's why we have the voting system. If no one else agrees with me, that's totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They were in the original animated *Transformers: The Movie* and were the [Quintessons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintessons).